# Map object data to view model function using ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created a knockout js component as follows:

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./details.html'], function(ko, htmlString) {

    function detailsViewModel(params) {
        var response = getDummyResponse();
        // how to extend the view model with ko.mapping.fromJS()?
    }

    function getDummyResponse(){
        return {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2
        };
    }

    return { viewModel: detailsViewModel, template: htmlString };
});
```

The returned view model needs to be a constructor function in order to be a valid knockout component.

Let's assume that `getDummyResponse()` returns a large object that I want to extend my view model with, using `ko.mapping.fromJS` to map the data.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that you need to specify a constructor function is incorrect. There are other [options](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#specifying-a-viewmodel). The one I suggest for your situation is a View Model factory.

From [the relevant docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-createviewmodel-factory-function):

> If you want to run any setup logic on the associated element before it is bound to the viewmodel, or use arbitrary logic to decide which viewmodel class to instantiate:
>
> ```
>    ko.components.register('my-component', {
>        viewModel: {
>            createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
>                // - 'params' is an object whose key/value pairs are the parameters
>                //   passed from the component binding or custom element
>                // - 'componentInfo.element' is the element the component is being
>                //   injected into. When createViewModel is called, the template has
>                //   already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound.
>                // - 'componentInfo.templateNodes' is an array containing any DOM
>                //   nodes that have been supplied to the component. See below.
>
>                // Return the desired view model instance, e.g.:
>                return new MyViewModel(params);
>            }
>        },
>        template: ...
>    });
> ```

In the factory method you can utilize `ko.mapping` if you so desire.

Comment: Followup question: How do I handle async loading in createViewModel? E.g. making an ajax call to load the model and then returning it

Comment: You should probably post a follow-up question on that, show us what you have so far and what the specific problem is. It's easier to help you that way with follow-up questions than in comments.

Comment: (On a whim though, you can either (a) make sure the outer view model is so that the component won't even be instantiated until the data is ready, or (b) you start with a "blanco" view model and have it load itself when being constructed. - But again, we need to see your current code, in a fresh question, to be able to really help.)

Comment: Thanks, I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025403/get-async-view-model-to-component Please have a look if you have time