# Get async view model to component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to fetch a view model from the server and use it in my component. Is it possible? My attempt, which obviously doesn't work:

```
function getDummyViewModelAsync(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       cb({ foo: 1 });
   }, 500);
}

ko.components.register('my-component', {
   viewModel: {
       createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {

           getDummyViewModelAsync(function(viewModel){
               return viewModel;
           });
       }
   },
   template: ...
});
```

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#an-amd-module-whose-value-describes-a-viewmodel

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, I'm aware of the docs. Did I miss something there? As far as I can tell, I can't accomplish this based on what I see there.

Comment: The section I linked is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @RoyJ After a second look, I still don't see how I should implement a callback or promise to load data before actually returning the view model...

Comment: You would need requirejs or some similar AMD system.

Comment: @RoyJ I use requirejs, sorry for not mentioning that. However, even if I make the viewmodel a require module, it will still be returned instantly, so the same problem still stands regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from our exchange in the comments what you are trying to do that cannot be done with the dynamic-loading modules. You can load your module structure dynamically, and of course you can populate elements of it dynamically.

If you want to do everything by hand instead, you can do that. Pass your viewmodel to the fetching function. Have the fetching function return a promise, and resolve it when it has fetched the data and put it in the viewmodel. Your template can even dynamically reference other templates, so you see one thing while loading and another when done.

```js
function getDummyViewModelAsync(populateMe) {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        populateMe.cb = ko.observable('A value');
        resolve('whatever');
      }, 500);
    }
  );
}

ko.components.register('my-component', {
  viewModel: {
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
      var vm = {
          template: ko.observable('loading'),
          ready: ready
        },
        ready = getDummyViewModelAsync(vm);
      ready.then(function() {
        vm.template('ready');
      });
      return vm;
    }
  },
  template: document.getElementById('selector').innerHTML
});

console.clear();
ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<template id='loading'>
  Loading...
</template>
<template id='ready'>
  Ta da!
  <div data-bind="text: cb"></div>
</template>
<template id='selector'>
  <!-- ko template: template -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</template>

<my-component></my-component>
```